# "Теплом" - какая это часть речи?

Tags: склонение

Слово "теплом" — какая это часть речи?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что недостаточно контекста для ответа. Пожалуйста, приведите конкретные примеры, чтобы мы могли дать ответы.

Comment: А нельзя сначала добавить такой (более понятный) комментарий: Приведите полностью предложение или словосочетание, в которое входит слово "теплом". Попробуйте дать свой ответ, который будет проверен и отредактирован на сайте.

Comment: @Jasmin конечно можно! Добавляйте!

Answer (score 1):

Тепло́м - тв. падеж слова *тепло*. Это **существительное**.

Comment: А форму прилагательного _теплый_ вы не рассматривали?

Comment: @Aer В прилагательном — ё:  тёплом.

Comment: а почему вы уверены, что здесь существительное, а не прилагательное?

Comment: @Aer , Надеюсь на автора, на то, что он указал бы, что там ё. А если не указал, то е.

Comment: Понимаю, но все-таки в таких ситуациях разумней попросить контекст, чтобы ответ был однозначным, а не, грубо говоря, на авось.

Comment: @Aer, Можно предложить оба варианта, третьего ведь не дано?

Comment: кажется, не дано, но тут важнее другое: подобный вопрос и ответы на него едва ли принесут пользу другим людям, ведь только автор знает, что он имел в виду.

Comment: @Aer, Если бы я видел, что вопрос объявлен требующим правки, я бы не отвечал, но оба события произошли одновременно.